# Unexpected token ':' in Nifi Expression Language

Tags: apache-nifi

I just got an error about an unexpected token while using the NiFi expression language.

```
'prod' validated against ${hostname:contains("prod")} is invalid because
Unexpected token ':' at line 1, column 10. Query: ${hostname:contains(prod)}
```

In this case the problem occurs in the RouteOnAttribute processor.

My question: What is/are the typical causes of this error?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is good to check the actual expression, however in this case I did not find any problems with the expression.

The problem comes from `hostname`

As [documented here](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDF3/HDF-3.4.1.1/expression-language-guide/content/structure.html):

> There also exist some functions that expect to have no subject. These functions are invoked simply by calling the function at the beginning of the Expression, such as ${hostname()}

After this it was quickly fixed by calling my attribute `host_name` instead.